# Eclipse ADT Plugin Not working

Tags: android, eclipse

I just updated eclipse and the Android Developer Tools plugin and now when I make a new project and try to run as android application, I get an error: "Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application". There is no visual errors (red x on the file name ). I have made several simple projects in the past with success. So I uninstalled eclipse and followed a couple tutorials step by step on setting up an Android developer environment with Eclipse Helios, Ganymede, Indigo with no success.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

thanks in advance.

***EDIT***
Thanks for the quick response. I did figure out the problem. Before the problem occurred, I had re-downloaded the android SDK changed the path. But then forgot to install a platform in the new environment.

Comment: Click Problems tab and find what the error is.

Comment: Right-click your project and choose properties. Then check your java build path for missing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

A common error is that there is a space in the Android toolkit filepath.  Make sure it is in a location like "C:/android/android-sdk" rather than something with spaces in it.

Give this a try, and if it doesn't work, please post the actual errors you are receiving.

EDIT:

This has apparently been fixed since r13 of the SDK tools, though it may still be an issue for older versions.

Comment: This has been fixed since [r13](http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html)

Comment: Good to know!  I'll edit my answer, though OP mentioned they tried several versions, so I'll keep my bit in :)